# Can't access Samba share after forwarding ports?

Tags: networking, server, samba, port-forwarding

I have forwarded my ports and can verify that they are open using a utility on Linux server. However, I can't actually connect to the samba share. Has anyone encountered this issue before and know how to fix this? VPN is not an option due to restrictions by my school.

Edit: more details

The ports I have tried forwarding are 137, 138, 139, and 445. Even after forwarding these ports I get the same error when trying to connect to the server outside my network as before. I know the ports are open because in a port utility on Linux it said that those ports were open and said linux next to it. Because of this I am assuming this is a problem with how something is setup on Linux?

Comment: More details please.

Comment: Details have been added

Comment: What is the exact error message you get when trying to connect?

Comment: "There was an error connecting to the server "<insertipaddresshere>".
The server may not exist or it is unavailable at this time. Check the server name or IP address, check your network connection, and then try again.

Comment: Are you connecting from a Windows pc? If so, I can't help.

Comment: No, I am connecting from a mac.

Comment: Then I DEFINITELY can't help.

Comment: Shouldn't it all be the same? I am just connecting using SMB.

Comment: I don't know the tools for testing on the client side.

Comment: I see. What if it is a problem on the Linux side?

Comment: Then testing on the client side would help determine that.

Comment: Oh. Okay. I have access to windows pc